# Adding a property to a GNU Radio OOT Module

Tags: python, gnuradio

I am new to GNU Radio and am working on a c++ sink OOT Module.  Everything works fine until I try to add a property that can change at runtime.  I have been looking at the Float to Short block as an example since it has a Scale property that can be changed at runtime.  When I try to duplicate the logic there I get this:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GrPybind.cmake:221 (message):
  Python bindings for dptt_dec.h are out of sync
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  python/dptt_dec/bindings/CMakeLists.txt:34 (GR_PYBIND_MAKE_OOT)
```

when I run the `cmake` command.  I backed out changes until dptt_dec.h looked just like the original generated code and the error went away.  If I just add a blank line to `dptt_dec.h` I get the error again.  I am sure I am missing something simple but I have not been able to figure it out after googling for quite a while.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[explanation I gave earlier today](https://matrix.to/#/!PiiKkGTcBDLmPnxhoT:gnuradio.org/$JE2UxQPtINhE4vYR7ecX0tmloAkn_lc4V1AB6ttqABQ?via=gnuradio.org&via=matrix.org&via=libera.chat)

You need to update the has in python/bindings/something.cc (or similar name). It's just the md5sum of something.h, you'll see a big comment at the top of the bindings/something.cc file